# What are the standard defintions of "counterclockwise" and "clockwise" in 3d space?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vectors

I'm in Calc III right now, and I'm a little confused as to what constitutes "clockwise", and "counterclockwise" rotations when dealing with the various planes in 3d-space.

Of course, it's obvious in the 2d plane which direction of rotation is clockwise, and which is counterclockwise, but I'm unsure how this extends to the $xy, yz, xz$, or even arbitrary planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Specifically, I'd like to know what the standard directions of rotation via the [standard definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) of the 3d rotation matrices (with their matrix-column vector products) are, and how/if that extends to rotations about arbitrary planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I'm sure its something to do with the right hand rule, but It's not intuitively obvious to me what, and It's surprising to me that neither Wikipedia, nor my text, mentions this explicitly (that I can find).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but from what it sounds like, you're looking for the Cartesian direction that a point will move in if rotated in some direction in $\mathbb{R}^3$. An infinitesimal rotation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ will move each point along it's tangent line. The direction of a counter-clockwise rotation is given by $(-y,x)$, and the direction of the clockwise rotation is $(y,-x)$.
In $\mathbb{R}^3$, it's almost just as easy to define the directions. The cross product of the rotation axis $\vec{n}$ by the point $\vec{p}$ gives the counter-clockwise tangent direction, and $\vec{p}\times\vec{n}$ gives the clockwise direction. In a left-handed system, these directions are flipped.
For a more geometric visualization of this, 3d rotations are just 2d rotations in the plane perpendicular to the rotation axis. In a right-handed system, counter-clockwise and clockwise directions are the same as they are in 2d.

Answer (score 0):

The 3d rotation matrices do not have a notion of clockwise or counterclockwise.  Even in 2d the rotation matrix for $\frac \pi 6$ clockwise is the same as $\frac {11 \pi}6$ counterclockwise.  From a rotation matrix you can determine the axis of the rotation, but the two directions of the axis are equivalent.  One will see the smaller rotation as clockwise, the other as counter.

Comment: You still need to specify a direction to rotate when defining the rotation, that's what I'm asking. When working with the $yz$ plane for example, if I rotate the **j** unit vector by $pi/2$ with the standard rotation matrix, is that rotating toward + **k**, or - **k**? How do I tell in general?

Comment: When you say $yz$ plane I think you have specified that rotations are from $y$ to $z$ but that is a special case.  If the plane is specified by a normal vector you have a right hand rule.  If the plane is specified by a linear equation, there is nothing to define one side from the other and you can't tell plus rotations from minus.

Comment: So assuming the plane is specified by a normal vector (which is actually how the standard rotation matrices are defined, I believe) if your thumb is pointing in the direction of the normal vector, rotation moves in the direction from your index finger to your middle finger? That's the thing here, I'm finding it really difficult to find a definition stating it explicitly like that.